# Xmlstarlet conditional select

Tags: xml, parsing, xpath, xml-parsing

I'm trying to select in my xml only the name of the section when id=1

This is a xml example:

```
<Raiz>
    <section name="name1" id="1">
        <entry title="title1"/>
    </section>
    <section name="name2 id="2">
        <entry title="title2"/>
    </section>
    <section name="name3" id="3">
        <entry title="title3"/>
    </section>
</Raiz>
```

I want to select the section name when id=1

Im trying with

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/Raiz/section/@name" -i id=1 file.xml
```

and

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/Raiz/section/@name" -i [@id=1] file.xml
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/Raiz/section/@name" -i "id=1" file.xml
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/Raiz/section/@name" -i @id=1 file.xml
```

but the output always is:

```
name1
name2
name3
```

How can I only select name1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using XPath predicate expression to filter `<section>` element by `id` attribute value :

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/Raiz/section[@id=1]/@name" file.xml
```